# Parse build.gradle programmatically

Tags: java, gradle

I am creating an automation solution that needs to parse and read a Gradle build, including `build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, and `gradle.properties`, and any submodules.  I know there is an API that include the `Project` class, which seems to be what I want.  The problem is that it is not obvious how to get an instance of a `Project` class.

Where in the API is the code to parse the build and return a `Project` instance?

Comment: I just upvoted this... I need the same thing. Gradle's build.gradle obviously replaces XML files in the case of Maven or Ant. It seems to me that the trouble is that a DSL configuration file, unlike an XML file, is dynamic, as it sits on top of an object (of class implementing `Project` in the case of Gradle) and helps execute the latter.  Nevertheless it should be possible to extract some info.  Just posted a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514521/extract-info-from-a-groovy-dsl-file

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use [Gradle's Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html). The entry point is [`GradleConnector`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/GradleConnector.html) class:

```
try(
    ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector()
        .forProjectDirectory(new File("/path/to/project"))
        .connect()
) {
    GradleProject project = connection.getModel(GradleProject.class);

    // Do some things with the project
    // project.getTasks().forEach(task -> { ... });
}
```

Comment: This is close but not quite what I was looking for.  I want to inspect the build, especially but not limited to dependencies.  The Project class (https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) is what I'm hoping to get an instance of.  The GradleProject appears to be mostly used for executing a build.