# Extract info from a Groovy DSL file?

Tags: parsing, groovy, logback, dsl

I recently switched my logback configuration file from logback.xml to logback.groovy. Using a DSL with Groovy is more versatile than XML for this sort of thing.

I need to analyse this file programmatically, like I analysed the previous XML file (any of innumerable parsing tools). I realise that this will be imperfect, as a DSL config file sits on top of an object which it configures and must be executed, so its results are inevitably dynamic, whereas an XML file is static.

If you want to include one Groovy file in another file there are  solutions.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004842/595305) worked for me.

But I'm struggling to find what I need from the results.

If I put a function like this in the DSL file ...

```
def greet(){
  println "hello world"
}
```

... not only can I execute it (`config.greet()` as below), but I can also see it listed when I go

```
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
    def config = shell.parse( logfileConfigPath.toFile() )
    println "config.class.properties ${config.class.properties}"
```

But if I put a line like this in the DSL file...

```
def MY_CONSTANT = "XXX"
```

... I have no idea how to find it and get its value (it is absent from the confusing and copious output from `config.class.properties`).

PS printing out `config.properties` just gives this:

```
[class:class logback, binding:groovy.lang.Binding@564fa2b]
```

... and yes, I did look at `config.binding.properties`: there was nothing.

***further thought***

My question is, more broadly, about what if any tools are available for analysis of Groovy DSL configuration files. Given that such a file is pretty meaningless without the underlying object it is configuring (an object implementing `org.gradle.api.Project` in the case of Gradle; I don't know what class it may be in the case of logback), you would have thought there would need to be instrumentation to kind of hitch up such an object and then observe the effects of the config file in a controlled, observable way. If Groovy DSL config files are to be as versatile as their XML counterparts surely you need something along those lines? NB I have a suspicion that `org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject` or `org.gradle.tooling.model.ProjectModel` might serve that purpose. Unfortunately, at the current time I am unable to get `GradleConnector` working, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514817/gradleconnector-could-not-determine-java-version-from-11-0-5).

I presume there is nothing of this kind for logback, and at the moment I have no knowledge of its DSL or configurable object, or the latter's class or interface...

Answer (score 1):

The use of `def` creates a local variable in the execution of the script that is not available in the binding of the script; see [this](https://www.groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_variables).  Even dropping `def` will not expose *MY_CONSTANT* in the binding because parsing the script via `GroovyShell.parse()` does not interpret/execute the code.

To expose *MY_CONSTANT* in `config`'s binding, change `def MY_CONSTANT = "XXX"` to `MY_CONSTANT = "XXX"` and execute the config script via `config.run()`.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting idea, although my aim is not to run the script but to examine it. Not at all surprisingly, `config.run()` doesn't work at all, because, and this is the point about a Groovy DSL config file, my logback.groovy is like a person riding an elephant: it is there to direct the underlying object.  So `config.run()` immediately threw a `MissingPropertyException` when it encountered the first property of the underlying "logback object". Other thing: I don't understand why a local variable is invisible but a local function is visible.

Comment: With regards to visibility, as mentioned [here](https://www.groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_variables), local/declared variables are declared in the compiler generated `run()` method.  So, it isn't accessible via the binding.  Also, after parsing, only an expression (not a value) can be associated with a variable.

Comment: @mikerodent There are ways to execute the Groovy DSL config file without leading to an exception (in all cases).  See [GafferConfigurator.run](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/4dd08e68321548cd85251ec389f5a832505e1268/logback-classic/src/main/groovy/ch/qos/logback/classic/gaffer/GafferConfigurator.groovy#L52) for how to do this.  Even so, peering into compiler generated `run()` method to access local/declared variables will be the hurdle.